# Find pdf of $x+y$ uniform $(\theta, \theta +1)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

How to find the pdf of $x+y$, where $x$, $y$ are iid and both are uniform $(\theta, \theta +1)$? I don't know how to divide intervals. I know how to solve if uniform $(0,1)$, since I can draw a square and use areas to analyze it. But I don't know how to solve out uniform $(\theta, \theta +1)$. I can use convolution, but after that, I don't know how to discuss intervals.

My attempt: I denote $Z=X+Y$ their sum. Then we have $f_X(x)=f_Y(y)=1 $ if $\theta\le x \le \theta+1$ and $0$ otherwise.

and the density function for the sum is given by

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\,dy.$$

Since $f_Y(y)=1$ if $\theta\le y \le \theta+1$ and 0 otherwise, this becomes

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} f_X(z-y)\,dy.$$

Now the integrand is 0 unless $\theta \le z-y \le \theta+1$, i.e., $z-\theta-1 \le y \le z-\theta$ and then it is 1 in this case.

I don't know how to do next.

Comment: Let $Z = X+Y$, then $P[Z = z] = P[Y = z-x | X = x]$. If you can do it for a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, you can do it for $[\theta, \theta + 1]$, it's just shifting the interval to the right by $\theta$.

Comment: @AmaanM Can you write down the solution?

Comment: Can you show us how you'd approach it if the distribution is $[0,1]$? Show us how far you can get and where you get stuck, and somebody will help point you in the right direction. Also, it's still a $1\times 1$ square, that shape doesn't change in this problem.

Comment: I add my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDF when $x$ and $y$ are uniform $(0,1).$
$$
P(Z\leq z)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{z^2}{2}& 0< z \leq 1\\
1-\frac{(2-z)^2}{2}& 1<z<2.
\end{cases}
$$

Taking the derivative, the PDF is
$$
f(z)=
\begin{cases}
z & 0<z\leq1\\
2-z & 1<z<2.
\end{cases}
$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform $(\theta,\theta+1),$ then $X-\theta$ and $Y-\theta$ are uniform $(0,1).$ Then $(X-\theta)+(Y-\theta)$ has the distribution given above. Then the PDF for $X+Y$ is $f$ translated by $2\theta.$
$$
f_{\theta}(z)=f(z-2\theta)=
\begin{cases}
(z-2\theta) &2\theta < z \leq 2\theta+1\\
2-(z-2\theta)& 2\theta+1 < z < 2\theta+2.
\end{cases}
$$